# How do I remove something after the second occurence in a column?

Tags: r, regex

One of my datafiles contains species names and accession number, the column is filled with names such as: `Ablepharus_kitaibelii_AY561364.1` and `Acanthodactylus_scutellatus_KX297057.1`.
I want to remove the parts after the second underscore _ in the entire column, to only have the species name.
However, i've tried commands as `sub("^([^_]*_[^_]*).","\\1",x)` but it doesn't work.
Anyone knows how to do this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c("Ablepharus_kitaibelii_AY561364.1", "Acanthodactylus_scutellatus_KX297057.1"))

df$new_name <- sub("^([^_]*_[^_]*).*", "\\1", df$name)
df
#>                                     name                    new_name
#> 1       Ablepharus_kitaibelii_AY561364.1       Ablepharus_kitaibelii
#> 2 Acanthodactylus_scutellatus_KX297057.1 Acanthodactylus_scutellatus
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>